# Fill out missing values in column

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table where i have a tendertype which shows which payment there has been done on a salesrow.

*UPDATE: Sorry i was not clear enough - It should be group by SalesHeader since another salesheader can have different values*

> In **Example 1** i only have records of one payment. This should be
> present on all record
>
> In **Example 2** i have 2 payments on all records. But i should only take
> one of them and fill out nulls, but leave the other one as it is.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
SalesHeader varchar(10),Amount int,TenderType nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES

('A',1   ,'MasterCard' ),
('A',10  ,NULL        ),
('A',100 ,NULL        ),
('A',10  ,NULL        ),
('A',1   ,NULL        ),
('B',1   ,'CASH'      ),
('B',100 , NULL        )
select * from @Table
```

[image: Image that shows how it looks like]

**What have i tried so far??**

```
SELECT 
  [Fakturanummer] as SalesHeader

  ,[Omsætning] as Amount
  
  ,a.[TenderType]
  ,x.TenderType 
FROM [CE_COG-BI-EDW].[dm].[SALG_TRANSAKTIONER] a 

CROSS APPLY(
select top 1 TenderType from  [CE_COG-BI-EDW].[dm].[SALG_TRANSAKTIONER] t
where TenderType is not null and a.Fakturanummer = t.Fakturanummer
)x

where DATASET = 'se' and   Fakturanummer in ('5133324','104893')
order by Fakturanummer
```

[image]

**Example 1:**

```
SalesHeader    | Amount    | TenderType
----------------------------------------
A                1           MasterCard
A                10          NULL
A                100         NULL
A                10          NULL
A                1           NULL
B                10          CASH
B                100         NULL
```

**Desired result 1**

```
SalesHeader    | Amount    | TenderType
----------------------------------------
A                1           MasterCard
A                10          MasterCard
A                100         MasterCard
A                10          MasterCard
A                1           MasterCard
B                1           CASH
B                100         CASH
```

**Example 2:**

```
SalesHeader    | Amount    | TenderType
----------------------------------------
A                1           MasterCard
A                10          CASH
A                100         NULL
A                10          NULL
A                1           NULL
```

**Desired result 2**

```
SalesHeader    | Amount    | TenderType
----------------------------------------
A                1           MasterCard
A                10          CASH
A                100         MasterCard
A                10          MasterCard
A                1           MasterCard
```

I tried with some `CROSS APPLY` but i can't get my head around it.

Comment: is the first example left join?

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Im not sure what you mean. Its how my table looks like

Comment: i didnt downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well. It helps to write about it. That got my mind cleard

It seems like i should only do like this, and thanks to @apomene comment with top 1 - I figured it out.

```
SELECT 
  [Fakturanummer] as SalesHeader

  ,[Omsætning] as Amount

  ,a.[TenderType]
  ,case when a.TenderType IS not null then a.TenderType else x.TenderType 
 end as newTenderType   
 FROM [CE_COG-BI-EDW].[dm].[SALG_TRANSAKTIONER] a 

 CROSS APPLY(
  select top 1 TenderType from  [CE_COG-BI-EDW].[dm].[SALG_TRANSAKTIONER] t
 where TenderType is not null and a.Fakturanummer = t.Fakturanummer
 )x

where DATASET = 'se' and   Fakturanummer in ('5133324','104893')
order by Fakturanummer
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTABLE
SET TenderType = (
        SELECT TOP 1 TenderType
        FROM myTable
        WHERE TenderType IS NOT NULL
        )
WHERE TenderType IS NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, look at my update. I forgot to write that i have serveral salesheader with different tendertypes. So it should only affect the desired salesheader